# Grid column not stretching across entire row

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following html in my html body

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">One</div>
  <div class="box2">Two</div>
  <div class="box3">Three</div>
</div>
```

with this as an inline-style

```
.wrapper { 
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 7fr;
} 
.box1 { 
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 1; 
  background-color: red;
}
.box2 { 
  grid-column: 1 / 1; 
  grid-row: 2 / 2; 
  background-color: blue;
}
.box3 { 
  grid-column: 2 / 2; 
  grid-row: 2 / 2; 
  background-color: green;
}
```

This might be not understanding the spec, but could anyone explain as to why I have to change box1 from

```
grid-column: 1 / 2;
```

to

```
grid-column: 1 / 3;
```

In order to make div1 span accross both columns?
See https://jsfiddle.net/vyx4jacm/

Comment: Try `.box1 { grid-column: 1 / -1; }` https://jsfiddle.net/vyx4jacm/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid-column` is short for `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end`. The second number of `grid-column` is your ending grid line.

Since you only specified 2 columns (via `grid-template-columns`) it means there would be 2 column tracks and **3** column grid lines. Thus to span *all* of them you require your `grid-column-end` value to be 3, not 2.

Comment: Ahh, that was the information I was mis-understand, thank you very much!